# Awk - How to escape the | in sub?

Tags: awk

I'd like to substitue a string, which contains a |

My STDIN :

> 13|Test|123|6232
>
> 14|Move|126|6692
>
> 15|Test|123|6152

I'd like to obtain :

> 13|Essai|666|6232
>
> 14|Move|126|6692
>
> 15|Essai|666|6152

I tried like this

> {sub("|Test|123","|Essai|666") ;} {print;}

But I think the | is bothers me.... I really need to replace the complete string WITH the |.

How should I do to get this result ?

Many thanks for you precious help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk '{sub(/\|Test\|123\|/,"|Essai|666|")}1' file
```

See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/78EO2U).

Note:

- `/\|Test\|123\|/` is a regex that matches `|Test|123|` substring
- `sub(/\|Test\|123\|/,"|Essai|666|")` - replaces the first occurrence of the regex pattern in the whole record (since the input is omitted, `$0` is assumed)
- `1` triggers the default `print` action, no need to explicitly call `print` here.